Cutting arcs of a torus so that the arcs of the inner and outer diameter are the same length
If I cut through a torus on a radial line, and then again at a $90°$ angle, I get a quarter of that torus, where the inner length and outer lengths differ. How do I calculate the angle i would have to cut the torus for the two lengths to be equal?
For example: If I have a roll of tape with radius of $30mm$ and inner radius of $20mm$ and cut it in this fashion, the inner piece of tape will be $π$ and the outer diameter will be $1½π$. What angle of the two cuts would result in the inner and outer length of tape pieces being equal? And I assume that the angle would differ based on the difference in the "toroidal thickness".

Not entirely sure what you're asking, but on a circle of radius $r$, an arc subtending angle $\theta$ (in radians) has length $r\theta$. Applying this to the inner and outer circles of a torus gives what you want. (If both angles have vertex on the axis of the torus, it's impossible: The subtended angles are equal, but the radii differ.)

"Torus" refers specifically to a donut/bagel/inner-tube shape. I.e. the cross-section of the cuts would be circular. Your tape roll example is an "annular cylinder". Its cross-section is a rectangle. If you are talking about cutting the shape with two planes passing through the axis of rotation, then Andrew D. Hwang is correct. It doesn't matter what angle is between the two planes, the inner length will always be shorter than the outer length, as both are proportional to the angle, with the outer proportion being greater.
